# flutter: How to use ImageFilter in CustomPaint without loosing opacity of layer

Tags: flutter

I am trying to create a cutout effect in Flutter using a blurred rectangle, as demonstrated in this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxkg7.png. I am using the `CustomPainter` class to achieve this effect and have included my current code below. However, my current implementation only produces the effect shown on the left side of the image.

```dart
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

class CutOutTextPainter extends CustomPainter {
  CutOutTextPainter({required this.text}) {
    _textPainter = TextPainter(
      text: TextSpan(
        text: text,
        style: TextStyle(
          fontFamily: 'Avenir',
          fontSize: 12,
          color: Colors.black,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
        ),
      ),
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
    );
    _textPainter.layout();
  }

  final String text;
  late final TextPainter _textPainter;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    // Draw the text in the middle of the canvas
    final textOffset =
        size.center(Offset.zero) - _textPainter.size.center(Offset.zero);
    final textRect = textOffset & _textPainter.size;

    final ImageFilter filter = ui.ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 1.0, sigmaY: 1.0);

    // The box surrounding the text should be 10 pixels larger, with 4 pixels corner radius
    final boxRect = RRect.fromRectAndRadius(textRect.inflate(4.5), const Radius.circular(10.0));

    final boxPaint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.white.withOpacity(1)
      ..blendMode = BlendMode.srcOut
      ..imageFilter = filter
      //..colorFilter = ColorFilter.mode(Colors.grey, BlendMode.);
      ..maskFilter = MaskFilter.blur(BlurStyle.inner, 10);

    canvas.saveLayer(boxRect.outerRect, Paint());
    // The box surrounding the text should be 10 pixels larger, with 4 pixels corner radius
    _textPainter.paint(canvas, textOffset);
    canvas.drawRRect(boxRect, boxPaint);
    canvas.restore();
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CutOutTextPainter oldDelegate) {
    return text != oldDelegate.text;
  }
}
```

Previously, I attempted to use `BackdropFilter` to produce the desired effect (as seen in the left side where it says "Fin de vente").